# Dotfuscator doesn't support current .NET framework?

Tags: dotfuscator

This is a Dotfuscator noob question -- I'm trying to run it on some assemblies for the first time, but I get an error saying: "Invalid assembly [foo.dll]. Input assembly [foo.dll] was compiled with a version of the .NET Framework (v4.0.30319) that is not supported by this version of Dotfuscator. Please check for an updated version of Dotfuscator."

I'm using the version that shipped with the current version of VS 2010, and I have all service packs etc installed. I have registered the product. Help > Check for updates doesn't do anything at all. I don't see any updated downloads on the Dotfuscator site.

Comment: Are you sure v4.0.30319 isn't a beta version? Did you install any beta products, such as Windows 7 SP1 Beta or a Visual Studio beta?

Comment: What a great comment. i would never have thought about it being a beta version.

Comment: According to this list, 4.0.30319 is the final release version of the framework. I do not have any beta versions of dev tools installed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions

Comment: have you tried compiling your code in an earlier framework like 2.0/3.5 and then trying to run Dotfuscator? maybe the version you have was pre .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note:  I work for PreEmptive Solutions on the Dotfuscator team.)

You likely have an older version of Dotfuscator (despite the behavior you are seeing under Check for Updates).  Dotfuscator does work with assemblies targeted at 4.0.30319, and has since the release of VS2010 (and we supported assemblies targeted at the various VS2010 Betas as they were released, too).

Are you using the free version included within Visual Studio?  If so, the version included in VS2008 will not support .NET 4.0 assemblies, and would also not indicate that updates are available.  This would be versioned as Community Edition v4.x.

The free version within VS2010 will handle 4.0.30319 targeted assemblies, and would be versioned as Community Edition 5.x.

The professional editions of Dotfuscator have supported builds against 4.0.30319 since April 2010 (http://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/dotfuscator-pro-change-log/272)

Please let me know which exact version of Dotfuscator you're using if it's a Community Edition version in VS2010 or a professional edition.

Comment: It looks like the problem was that I was running Dotfuscator from the start menu, which launches the VS2008 version. I found Tools > Dotfuscator Software Services in VS2010 and that got me the right version.